# Find the domain of the trig function

Tags: functions, trigonometry, inverse-function

Find the domain of the function.

$f(x)=({2+\cos 2x-\sin2x*\tan x})$^1/2

$2+\cos2x-\sin2x*\tan x≥0$

**Simplifying**

$-4\sin^2x+3≥0$

$\sin^2x≤3/4$

$-3/4≤\sin x≤3/4$

$\arcsin(-3/4)≤x≤\arcsin(3/4)$

My answer is - x ∈($\pi - \arcsin(3/4);\pi+\arcsin(3/4)∪(\arcsin(-3/4);\arcsin(3/4).$

Can someone check it, please?(i made an error during the last part, can someone check it with this error? xdd)

Comment: $-\sqrt 3/2  \lex \sin x\leq \sqrt 3/2$

Comment: @Matteo Ahhh, yes, can someone check it with my error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last part is wrong, or at least incomplete. The condition you arrived at was equivalent to $|\sin x | \leq \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. Take a look at $|\sin x|$... In $[0, 2\pi]$ this condition is satisfied for $x \in [0, \frac{\pi}{3}] \cup [\frac{2\pi}{3}, \frac{4 \pi}{3}] \cup [\frac{5\pi}{3}, 2 \pi] $. taking into account the period of $\sin$ the condition is satisfied in an infinite union of closed intervals given by
$$
\bigcup_{k\in \mathbb{Z}} \left([2k\pi, \frac{\pi}{3}+2k\pi] \cup [\frac{2\pi}{3}+2k\pi, \frac{4 \pi}{3}+2k\pi] \cup [\frac{5\pi}{3}+2k\pi, 2 \pi+2k\pi]\right) 
$$

Comment: In other words $\cup_{k\in \Bbb Z} [k\pi-\pi/3,\,k\pi+\pi/3].$